# jquery jtable change row color in Asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, grid, jquery-jtable

In jquery jtable, I Want to Change Some Row's color's.
For examlpe for rows that have columns with "mineId=1" row color change to red.
How Can I perform this Action?
for one column :

```
mineid: {
title: 'mineid',
display: function (data) {
    if(data.record.mineid == 2)
      return '<b style="background-color:red !important; display:block !important;">' + data.record.mineid + '</b>';
    else
      return data.record.mineid;
}
```

}

But I want for whole row change color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this one to apply your style:

```
recordsLoaded: function (event, data) {
        for (var i in data.records) {
            if (data.records[i].mineid == 2) {
                $('#MineTableContainer').find(".jtable tbody tr:eq(" + i + ")").css("cssText", "background-color:red !important; color:white !important;");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Giulio if you to want to be familiar with `find` function, you can just google it ;)